# Unable to find Column Name after Transpose

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

After transposing my Python Dataframe, I could not access my column name to plot a graph. I want to choose two columns but failed. It keeps saying no such column names. I am pretty new to Python, dataframe and transpose. Could someone help please?

Below is my input file and I want to transpose row to Column. It was successful when I transposed but I could not select "Canada" and "Cameroon" to plot a graph.

```
    country     1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995
0   Cambodia    65.4    65.7    66.2    66.7    67.1    68.4
1   Cameroon    63.9    63.7    64.7    65.6    66.6    67.6
2   Canada      98.6    99.6    99.6    99.8    99.9    99.9
3   Cape Verde  77.7    77.0    76.6    89.0    79.0    78.0
```

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re 
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    missing_values=["n/a","na","-","-","N/A"]
    df = pd.read_csv('StackoverflowGap.csv', na_values = missing_values)
    # Transpose
    df = df.transpose()
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.plot(df['Canada','Cameroon'], linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.title("Time Series for Canada")
    plt.show()
```

It produces a long list of error messages but the final message is

KeyError: ('Canada', 'Cameroon')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a few things you might need to do when working with the data.

1. If the csv file has no header then use `df = pd.read_csv('StackoverflowGap.csv', na_values = missing_values, header = None)`.
2. When you transpose, you need to name the columns
   `df.columns= df.iloc[0]`.
3. Having done this you need to drop the first row of your table (because it contains the column names) `df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))`.
4. Finally, when accessing the data by columns (in the `plt.plot()` command) you need to use `df[]` on the list of columns, i.e. `df[['Canada', 'Cameroon']]`.

**EDIT** So the code, as it works for me is as follows

```py
df = pd.read_csv('StackoverflowGap.csv', na_values = missing_values, header = None)
df = df.T
df.columns= df.iloc[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop('country'))
df.index.name = 'Year'
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(df[['Canada','Cameroon']], linewidth = 0.5)
plt.title("Time Series for Canada")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the “header = None” and it is fine. Next.
I added the “df.colmuns= df.iloc[0]” before transpose, and when I ran, I got a warning message. “Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access”

After I transposed, and ran “df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))”, I lost all my column names such as “Canada”

This is what I got left:

 1 2 3 4
1 65.4 63.9 98.6 77.7
2 65.7 63.7 99.6 77
3 66.2 64.7 99.6 76.6
4 66.7 65.6 99.8 89
5 67.1 66.6 99.9 79
6 68.4 67.6 99.9 78

Comment: sorry, I had a typo in point 2. I've fixed the code there, but you need to run it after you transpose.

Comment: Bates, I completed part 3 and got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0c14a71d80aa> in <module>()
----> 1 df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   4385             if errors != 'ignore':
   4386                 raise KeyError(
-> 4387                     'labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
   4388             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   4389         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: 'labels [0] not contained in axis'

Comment: I see what's happened here, its a simple fix. Instead of `df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))` type `df = df.reindex(df.index.drop('country'))`. After this you can also type  `df.index.name = 'Year'`. I will add it above in an edit.

Comment: Hi Col Bates, I tried your codes and got the following errors: 

KeyError: "labels ['country'] not contained in axis"

Comment: Hi Bates, yes, it is working. Thank you.  The funny thing is that it does not run in one go. I have to break down into different parts and run it individually before the graph is plotted.  Not sure why? It could be Jupyter Notebook.